# Django Form & Bootstrap Select

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to add additional fields to a Django form using Bootstrap select. I currently have these two models:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    pic = models.ImageField()

Class Choice
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and a form containing this widget:

```
widgets = {
        'organisation': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control selectpicker', 'data-live-search':'true'}),
},
```

This is working correctly and is rendering the drop down select form on the template. **However, I also want to show the image and topic like so:**

(my template currently)

```
 <div class="col-md-12">{% bootstrap_field form.organisation show_label=False %}</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<option data-thumbnail="Organisation.pic" data subtext="Organisation.topic">Organisation.title</option>
```

or alternatively, display results grouped by topic:

```
<optgroup label="Topic1">
      <option data-thumbnail="Organisation.pic"> Organisation.title</option>
      <option data-thumbnail="Organisation2.pic"> Organisation2.title</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Topic2">
      <option data-thumbnail="Organisation3.pic"> Organisation3.title</option>
 </optgroup>
```

I've tried to do this directly in the template using a for loop for each option (i.e for x, org in form.fields.organisation.choices), however it doesn't pull in any other fields beyond the organisation title (organisation.topic and organisation.pic.url, don't seem to work)?

Comment: Is your last code block your actual template? If not, can you supply it?

Comment: @user7733611 - have now added this line - {% bootstrap_field form.organisation show_label=False %}